# MySQL Trigger: removes session expire older than 1 hour

Tags: mysql

**What am I doing wrong?**

Delete all session entries older than 3 hours.
Do not perform this deletion until a new session is saved.

I'm trying to create a **trigger** on phpMyAdmin interface:

- table: oc_session
- time: before
- event: insert
- definition:

```sql
delete from `oc_session` where `session`.expire <DATE_SUB (NOW (), INTERVAL 3 HOUR)
```

[image]

**result:**
after this setting, you can no longer log in to the shop: after the login attempt you will be redirected to the login page - presumably the current session will be deleted immediately?

**expected:**

> there are only session entries from the last 3 hours, all older session entries are deleted.

Comment: please add the full create trigger..end

Comment: @P.Salmon sorry, i don't know what you mean

Comment: Are you using a wizard to create the trigger ? If you SHOW CREATE TRIGGER <triggername> you can then copy the code to the question. You should also read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html and (in my view) only use wizards sparingly.

Comment: @P.Salmon now i have put a picture in it

Comment: MYSQL will not allow to delete from the table which fired the trigger. Consider putting the insert and delete into a procedure wrapping in a transaction or creating an event to periodically tidy up.

Comment: @P.Salmon that means there is no solution?

Comment: 'that means there is no solution' - i mentioned 2

Comment: @P.Salmon Thanks!!!